# Minimal Navigation for Chromium Kiosk

Tags: raspbian, debian, chromium, kiosk

I am running a lightweight Raspberry Pi web kiosk intended to provide public access only to our library website. However, I need a way for users to navigate back, forward and home without having full access to the address bar.

I am using Chromium in kiosk mode on Openbox. It's imperative that the website be full screen (no window decorations) however I would like to have a simple navigation panel overlaid on top.

So far, I have tried creating a tint2 top panel, but I can't seem to get Openbox to allow the panel to display over a full-screened application. I have also tried iFraming the site in a local html doc served via Apache, but the website team (for good reason) are unwilling to investigate a server-side exception to our framebusting.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, workarounds or creative solutions that might allow me to keep our website full screen on the kiosks, but allow users to navigate back or home should they get lost.

Comment: did you mange to find a solution ?

Comment: Very late reply, but in short: no. Ended up allowing the address bar to be displayed and restricting the whitelisted ips to our servers instead.